# influence git commit intervals on Overleaf

Tags: overleaf, git

I use the git feature in Overleaf to mirror the repo containing the document to my own server. We have a code review system where every commit has to be confirmed by another team member. Overleaf creates a LOT of intermediate commits. When writing COMMIT a sentence COMMIT therCOMMITe will be a commit COMMIT every few words. The setup is not really usable that way.

I am a little bit lost trying to improve the situation. Does anyone have experience with the git bridge? How would you configure it in my situation? What triggers a commit? Assuming commits are triggered by a timer: Can I change the interval to maybe once per 10 minutes? Is it possible to have manual commits instead of auto-commit where I could even add a helpful commit message. (I assume the answer is „no“).

Comment: Hi - I think this question might be considered off-topic. If you have questions about Overleaf you can direct them to Overleaf support: support[at]overleaf.com. I'm on the support team, and we're happy to answer your questions. Generally: The git-bridge doesn't create a commit every few words and is not based on a timer. When you issue a pull, if no commit exists for the current project state, a new commit is created. When you push files from your local, a commit is created. You can influence this somewhat and create intermediary commits by creating a labeled version in your Overleaf history.

Comment: So basically, while the files are being edited, every pull creates a commit. Thus, if my hosted mirrored repo polls at a high frequency, that might causing my problems...